# Angular multipart form data upload webapi 404

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, asp.net-web-api2, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload a file from AngularJS to ASP.NET WebAPI. For some reason, it is being rejected by WebAPI with a 404 status code. Here's the code:

Angular JS:

```
function upload(file, assessmentId, progressCallback) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file, file.name);
    formData.append('assessmentId', assessmentId);

    // post the file
    return $http({
        data: formData,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
        method: 'POST',
        url: _api('api/video/upload')
    });
}
```

Also tried:

```
function upload(file, assessmentId, progressCallback) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file, file.name);
    formData.append('assessmentId', assessmentId);

    return $http.post(_api('api/video/upload'), formData, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
    });
}
```

C# WebApi:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/video/upload")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Upload()
{
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);

    /* do stuff */

    return Ok(new { test = "ing" });
}
```

If I comment out `formData.append('file', file, file.name);` so only appending the `assessmentId`, WebApi accepts the request.

`file` is from the HTML file upload control: `element[0].files[0]`. I wonder if that's where the error is?

Another thing to note is in the Chrome Developer Tools Console, after the 404 POST error, there's a CORS error on the same request. I've seen this occur before when WebApi fails, but I don't think there is actually a CORS error because it works when I exclude the file from the request.

**Update**
The plot thickens. It works fine with small files (a few MB). If I upload a 27MB file, I get a 500 error stating "Maximum request length exceeded". Great! Getting somewhere. But if I upload a 56MB file, I get the 404 status code. What's going on here?

With the following config, the 27MB file works, but the 56MB file still returns 404.

```
<location path="api/video/upload">
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="86400" maxRequestLength="4194304" />
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Have you tried using file-upload directives of AngularJs

Comment: @RohanKawade no, but I've used this same code elsewhere (with Angular Audio Recorder) and it works fine.

Comment: @RohanKawade However I'm using a directive derived from [here](https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs) to bind the input element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, with fresh eyes, I've reach the cause. There are yet more config settings to limit the request size in ASP.NET. The code in the OP is fine. This configuration is required (4GB limit):

```
<location path="api/video/upload">
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="86400" maxRequestLength="4194303" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

And for the sake of this answer being a full solution, here's the code again:

**Angular JS Service Operation:**

```
upload: function (file, assessmentId, progressCallback) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file, file.name);
    formData.append('assessmentId', assessmentId);

    // post the file
    return $http({
        data: formData,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
        method: 'POST',
        url: _api('api/video/upload')
    });
}
```

**WebApi Action:**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/video/upload")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Upload()
{
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);

    /* do stuff */

    return Ok(new { test = "ing" });
}
```

**WebAPI web.config:**

```
<location path="api/video/upload">
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="86400" maxRequestLength="4194303" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```